# catching exception from boost::filesystem::is_directory

Tags: c++, boost, exception

I am currently catching errors from boost::filesystem::is_directory and showing the error to the user by calling "what()" on the exception.  This gives the reason for failure but the error is strange to the user.  For example:

> boost::filesystem::is_directory: Access is denied

How can I catch the boost error and figure out what the actual cause is, so I can show a nicer error message?

Comment: Boost.FileSystem exceptions are implemented in terms of [Boost.System](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/system/doc/index.html) -- have you read its docs?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By "nicer error message" would you mean something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path p("/proc/1/fd/1");
    try {
       boost::filesystem::is_directory(p);
    } catch(const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& e)
    {
       if(e.code() == boost::system::errc::permission_denied)
           std::cout << "Search permission is denied for one of the directories "
                     << "in the path prefix of " << p << "\n";
       else
           std::cout << "is_directory(" << p << ") failed with "
                     << e.code().message() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you might need to catch boost::filesystem::wfilesystem_error is the path you specified was using wchar_t*